# Google Service Account: androidpublisher Insufficient permissions to perform the requested operation

Tags: php, android, google-play-console, android-inapp-purchase, google-api-console

I know this question has been asked for several times here but none of the solution worked for me.

Following are the steps I followed to create a service account:

- Logged in to Google Play Console account.
- Then navigated to Settings > API Access from the left panel.
- Scrolled down to Service Accounts section and clicked on Create Service Account.
- Followed the instruction mentioned on dialog opened.
- While creating service account on Google API Console selected Service account Permissions as Project > Owner
- Created key and downloaded in json format.
- Now came back to Google Play Console and clicked on Grant Access to grant permission as Administrator.

Now I am using this service account to validate In App Purchases on server but I am getting this error:

```
{
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "androidpublisher",
    "reason": "permissionDenied",
    "message": "The current user has insufficient permissions to perform the requested operation."
   }
  ],
  "code": 401,
  "message": "The current user has insufficient permissions to perform the requested operation."
 }
}
```

I am using this php [lib](https://github.com/aporat/store-receipt-validator) and service account method to verify purchases.

Comment: any solution ??

Comment: I contacted Google Play Console regarding the issue through their support and the issue got fixed

Comment: @SagarGuhe may I ask how is it fixed?